# The missing HTTP Verbs in MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, caldav, http-verbs

I'm trying to create a simple CalDav server using ASP.NET MVC 3, but the lack of the missing HTTP Verbs got me confused.

How can I add them and use them? Maybe I could create an `ActionFilter` for each one of the missing native ones...

[RFC 4791](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4791#section-5.1.1) says that a CalDav protocol can use all of this verbs

> *OPTIONS*, **GET**, HEAD, **POST**, **PUT**, **DELETE**, TRACE, *COPY*, *MOVE*, PROPFIND, PROPPATCH, LOCK, UNLOCK, REPORT, ACL

In **Bold** are shown the native MCV3 verbs, and *Italic* the ones I want to implement in order to create a simple CalDav (will be open source on GIT, using [DDay.iCal Library](https://sourceforge.net/projects/dday-ical/) but I just need to start) :)

Is there anything that I can't find out there available?

Comment: did you have a chance to get started on this project?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at the `AcceptVerbsAttribute`. It takes a string array which I would imagine you could supply the ones you are looking for.

Comment: I was looking at the `ActionMethodSelectorAttribute` ... will look at that one as well!

Comment: @Daniel - Is the AcceptVerbsAttribute necessary for PUT and DELETE? GET/POST obviously work right out the box.

Comment: @one.beat.consumer No, unless you want to explicitly filter the requests.

Comment: Thanks for this. I used it to implement an action for `OPTIONS`.